# django tried these url patterns

Tags: regex, django, url, admin

When I try to access my site, it gives me the following: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

If I go to the site and append /admin, it takes me to the admin page. If I comment out the line enabling the admin, it works properly. How do I get both? The first pattern in urlpatterns is '', so I don't understand why that messes up when I enable the admin. (Note: I am just doing the tutorial.)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
#url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^x/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common problem.

When there are no urlpatterns defined at all, Django gives you the "It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page" message, but as soon as you define any urlpattern that goes away.

You're getting that error because you have not defined a urlpattern for the root url, just one for "/admin". Continue through the tutorial until it teaches you how to add your own urlpatters.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty odd. I assumed that the '' would be constant even if the admin one was added.

Comment: It normally is, but Django makes an exception when there are zero patterns. The fact that the pattern you added was the admin isn't significant, just that you added any pattern at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your default pattern with:

```
url(r'^$', 'foo'),
```

Instead of:

```
url(r'', 'foo'),
```

Your tutorial may be outdated.

Comment: Hmm, now it gives me an AttributeError: "'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'"

Comment: Can you paste your urls.py in your first post? :)

Comment: Done. (Also, I think I'm using the most recent tutorial...)

Comment: I've just tried locally and it worked with your urls.py (on 1.4). I would check the ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-ROOT_URLCONF) Otherwise I can't help sorry.

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF is 'sales.urls'. I'm on 1.5. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

enter to: localhost/admin and use

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 admin.autodiscover()}
```

in your url.py