# django urls: "Django tried these URL patterns"

Tags: django

I am trying a tutorial on Django called blog. I have the following structure:

```
FirstBlog|FirstBlog
settings
urls
__init__
etc

blog
templates | index.html
migrations
views.py

manage.py
```

The `view.py` has

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from blog.models import posts

def home(request):
    return render('index.html')
```

The `urls.py` has

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog', 'FirstBlog.blog.views.home',name='home'),
]
```

and I get this error:

Using the `URLconf` defined in `FirstBlog.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: `^blog [name='home']`

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

I can't seem to get it right..
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django tried these url patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157393/django-tried-these-url-patterns)

Answer (score 3):

You are requesting for `/` url and you have not saved any such mapping. Current mapping is for `/blog` . So it will work for the same url.
i.e goto the browser and request `/blog`

If you need it to work for `/` then change the urls appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

within your blog app, create a `urls.py` file and add the following code which calls the *home* view.

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^',views.home, name='home'),

]
```

then in your root urls file which can be found at *FirstBlog/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/',include('blog.urls')), #when you visit this url, it will go into the blog application and visit the internal urls in the app
]
```

PS:
your templates should be in *blog/templates/blog/index.html*

Read [this docs on templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/)  to understand how django locates templates.

This one is to understand how urls work [Urls dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in the wrong way! Try doing that using `TemplateView` from class-based views, which are the current standard from django views.

Check the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/

Use this at the `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

And then, create a folder called `templates` in the project root ( like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something ) named `index.html`

Comment: Did that with the same error: Current url didnt match any of these. (^blog/). The templates folder is right under my app directory, the same place where views.py, models.py the folder migrations is etc. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to file then select Save all your project instead of save. Or use shortcut Ctrl +k s on windows. Project should be able to sync and display the code on Django interface

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).